# Поворот спрайта Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d, спрайт

Вот написал скрипт для патрулирования уровня. Данный персонаж двигается только по двум точкам. Не могу разобраться как сделать поворот спрайта на 180 градусов при достижении точки.

```
public class WalkingMonster : Entity
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _path;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed;

    //private Vector3 dir;
    //private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private Transform[] _points;
    private int _currentPoint;
    private void Start()
    {
        //dir = transform.right;
        _points = new Transform[_path.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < _path.childCount; i++)
        {
            _points[i] = _path.GetChild(i);
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        Transform target = _points[_currentPoint];
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, _speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position == target.position)
        {
            _currentPoint++;
            
            if (_currentPoint >= _points.Length)
            {
            //    sprite.flipX = dir.x > 0.0f;
                _currentPoint = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В path я закидываю пустой Gameobject, у которого 2 дочерних элемента (2 точки)

Answer (score 1):

[Документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer.html) же есть:

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true; // по оси X
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = true; // по оси Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем разобрался с вашим методом, потом думаю еще пока сделал так:

```
if (transform.position == target.position)
    {
        _currentPoint++;
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, -180, 0);
        if (_currentPoint >= _points.Length)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);      
            _currentPoint = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

я так полагаю что у вас объект нужно повернуть весь, а не только его спрайт. Попробуйте его `rotation` умножить на `-1`, так вы должны развернуть его по горизонтали.

`transform.rotation = new Vector3(float x, float y * -1, float z)`.

Если это вам не подойдет, то можно попробовать вместо этого умножить его `transform.localScale` также на `-1`.